# Escape sequence inconsistency in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I am using Python 3 and I wanted to see the difference between the raw/real representation and the string representation of using escape sequences for single-quotes and double-quotes, so I created the following script:

```
raw = "%r" % "\'\""
str = "%s" % "\'\""

print(raw)
print(str)
```

print(str) returns (as expected):

```
'"
```

Now I expected the print(raw) to return:

```
'\'\"'
```

However it returns:

```
'\'"'
```

Why is there only one backslash present in the print(raw) statement, shouldn't there be two, as this would reflect value that I have parsed into the formatted string? I'm sorry for the stupid question..

Comment: You want to create a raw literal: `r"\'\""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`r` doesn't stand for `raw`, it stands for `repr`. [Using `%r` invokes `repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) on the object. Quoting the [`repr()` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

> this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval()

The source-code strings `'\'"'` and `"\'\""` are two representations of  equivalent objects.

Comment: I see now that they can be seen as equivalent, but do you have any idea why one backslash remained over the other? Or is this a quirk of Python?

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee which representation is chosen, as long it represents the string object. The two shortest possible representations would be: `'\'"'` and `"'\""`. (Remember that `'` and `"` are equivalent in Python, unlike Bash or C.) As to why `repr()` chooses the `'...'` form over the `"..."`, I have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

> ... print(raw) ...

Nope. The "r" stands for "representation", not "raw". But how the string literal was written is lost as soon as the code is compiled, and cannot be retrieved regardless.